# SQL Server : Joining two pivot tables

Tags: sql, join, pivot

I'm trying to create join a table with itself. So for example below the table pivots based on the sum of D (Debits) and C (Credits) however I need to join the table with itself to add additional columns displaying count of an "D" entry and "C" plus two more additional columns showing the overall sum and overall count. How do I join the table below to create the additional columns?

Input table

```
GL_BU   GL_Source   GL_JE_Type          GL_Amount   Amount_Prefix
------------------------------------------------------------------
202     Payables    Purchase Invoices        1234               C
202     Payables    Purchase Invoices         123               D
202     Inventory   Inventory                 123               C
202     Payables    Purchase Invoices        1234               C
```

Output Table

```
GL_BU GL_Source   GL_JE_Type    Amount D Amount C Count D Count C Total Count Total Amount
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
202   Spreadsheet XXXXX         1234     123            1        1          2      1357
202   Manual      XXXXX         1234     123            2        2          4      1357
202   Manual      XXXXX         1234     123            1        1          2      1357
202   Inventory   XXXXX         1234     123            4        4          8      1357
202   Sales Order XXXXXX        1234     123            1        1          2      1357
```

Current Code

```
SELECT *
    FROM 
            (SELECT 
                    [GL_Business_Unit]
                    ,[GL_Source]
                    ,[GL_JE_Type]
                    ,([GL_Amount])
                    ,[Amount_Prefix]
              FROM [03_rdm].[table_2013]) as t
                Pivot(SUM([GL_Amount])
                FOR [Amount_Prefix] IN (D,C)) AS pvt1
```

Current code link in SQLFiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/92369/2

Comment: Hmm, any chance you can post your table structure, sample data and then the final desired result?  Or even create a http://sqlfiddle.com/ with it?

Comment: Ive jsut updated with the sample input and desired output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your sample data doesn't match your desired result so I'm guessing that this is what you need.  You could use a PIVOT to get the result, but it seems that this would be much easier to get this using an aggregate function and some conditional logic via a `CASE` expression:

```
select 
  GL_BU,
  GL_Source,
  GL_JE_Type,
  sum(case when Amount_Prefix = 'D' then GL_Amount else 0 end) Amount_D,
  sum(case when Amount_Prefix = 'C' then GL_Amount else 0 end) Amount_C,
  sum(case when Amount_Prefix = 'D' then 1 else 0 end) Count_D,
  sum(case when Amount_Prefix = 'C' then 1 else 0 end) Count_C,
  count(*) TotalCount,
  sum(GL_Amount) TotalAmount
from table_2013
group by GL_BU, GL_Source, GL_JE_Type;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/08af2/2)

Comment: That is a far simpler way of doing it. Thnak you.